# c# split list in sublists based on parameter value

Tags: c#

Do apologise if the question is duplicate but I couldn't find the answer.

I have a list of postcodes which I want to split into two different lists based on validity example given below.

```
private List<LogRecord> records = new List<LogRecord> ( );
```

> rowid postcode validity
>
> 1111  XXXX XX   invalid
>
> 2222  AA99 9AA  Valid

I am trying to do something like that

```
var result = records.GroupBy ( item => item.Validity ).ToList ( );

var validPostCodes = result.First ( );
var InvalidPostCodes = result.Last ( );

string ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join ( "," , validPostCodes );
string InvalidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join ( "," , InvalidPostCodes );

SaveFiles.SaveDataSuccess ( ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs );
SaveFiles.SaveDataFail ( InvalidFormattedPostCodeLogs );
```

Please help where i am going wrong

**[EDIT]**

I want to save the rowid postcodes and validity as well in the csv file so after converting it the result in the csv file should be like this

> row id, postcode,validity
>
> 11111,XXXX XX, invalid

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Do you override `ToString` in `LogRecord`?

Comment: it is not converting the "string ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join ( "," , validPostCodes );" into csv format.

Comment: step through with a debugger. "not converting": does that mean there is an exception, or the result is just empty?

Comment: Ok, that's the problem. Does it throws an exception? Does the string generated contain wrong data? You should give us as much information as possible, as we cant see your computer

Comment: Its not throwing any exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead for two separate lists, why don't you try with a Dictionary? I mean something like this:

```
var result = records.GroupBy(item => item.Validity )
                    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.ToList());
```

So that `result["Valid"]` will gives you the List of Valid items and `result["InValid"]` will give you the list of invalid items. which means the output can be taken as :

```
string ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join("," , result["Valid"]
                                                     .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());
string InvalidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join ( "," , result["InValid"].Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());
```

The best option for formatting the output is `overrides` `ToString` as like the following:

```
public class LogRecord
{
    // ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}",this.row_id,this.PostCode,this.validity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution but in the "string ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join("," , result["Valid"]
                                                     .Select(x = x.ToString()).ToList());" it is not recognizing the x parameter

Comment: @CrazyEngineer: Sorry for the mistake as well as late replay, it should be `.Select(x => x` instead for `.Select(x = x`

Answer (score 2):

`string.Join` calls `ToString` on the elements in the provided sequence. So you probably did not override `ToString()` in your `LogRecord` class. You can either override `ToString()` or create the string directly like this:

```
string ValidFormattedPostCodeLogs = String.Join (Environment.NewLine , 
                      validPostCodes.Select(pc => $"{pc.RowID}, {pc.PostCode}, {pc.Validity}));
```

Note that `validPostCodes` still is a sequence of `LogRecord` instances. So you want to join them using `Environment.NewLine` as seperator. `,` is the separator between "columns", the properties of a `LogRecord`.